# How to simulate back button when testing Ember.js apps?

Tags: testing, ember.js

In my acceptance tests, I would like to simulate the back button click and results transitions.

I have the following, but I have a feeling that its wrong.

```
test("back to search page", function(){
  visit('/')
    .then(function(){
      return fillIn('.search input', 'hi');
    })
    .then(function(){
      return click('.search button');
    })
    .then(function(){
      // I want to go back here
      return visit('/');
    })
    .then(function(){
      var keyword = find('.search input').val();
      equal(keyword, '');
      ok(!exists('.search .results'));
    });
})
```

**What's the right way to simulate back button in tests?**

Answer (score 8):

`window.history.back()` or `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: This doesn't work when used with tests because it forces the entire window back 1, not the route. It will basically take it to a different page.

Comment: This is because tests by default use the NoneLocation which doesn't track history at all. You will have to change your location to HashLocation if you want to test the back functionality, or do what you are currently doing.

Comment: Do you have any reference for how HashLocation is set?

Comment: With Ember 2.2.0 / Ember CLI 1.13.13, setting `locationType` to `hash` does not work. The browser test window appears blank with a console error that it cannot find module "Ember".

Comment: Is there another way to do this with Ember 2.2 and onward (working in 2.15/2.16 currently) ?

Answer (score 3):

To make `window.history.back()` work you need to use `location : 'hash'` in your `Router`

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'hash'
});
```

Here's the official documentation about setting the location type:  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

Answer (score 1):

I have written test helpers to simulate back and forward browser navigation buttons and published them as an ember-cli addon: [ember-cli-browser-navigation-button-test-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-browser-navigation-button-test-helper)

They expose 3 test helpers: `backButton`, `forwardButton`, `setupBrowserNavigationButtons`. The last own registers a service, which logs location changes and uses transitions to go back or forward.

It also works with default `location: 'none'`.